# Removing article pages from the footnotes using Historische Zeitschrift Style

Tags: biblatex

I use this command to remove pages from the footnotes when the `incollection` is quoted but to leave them in the bibliography.

```
  \renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
      \printfield{chapter}%
      \newunit}%
```

and:

```
  \renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
      \printfield{chapter}%
      \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
      \printfield{pages}%
      \newunit}%
```

Does anyone know how to adapt this to also work for the `article`?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
     citecolor=black,
     filecolor=black,
     linkcolor=black,
     urlcolor=black
}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@incollection{athanasius1857,
        Address = {Parisiis},
        Author = {{Athanasius Alexandrinus}},
        Booktitle = {Patrologiae cursus completus: Series Graeca},
        Editor = {Jacques Paul Migne},
        Pages = {37-40},
        Publisher = {Accurante J.-P. Migne},
        Shortauthor = {Ath.},
        Shorttitle = {ep. Marcell.},
        Title = {Epistula ad Marcellinum de interpretatione psalmorum},
        Volume = {27},
        Year = {1857}}
@article{stead1997,
    Author = {Christopher Stead},
    Call-Number = {X2 rewa},
    Date-Added = {2014-07-20 08:23:48 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-07-20 08:25:04 +0000},
    Journal = {Studia Patristica},
    Keywords = {secondary},
    Pages = {39-52},
    Title = {Was Arius a Neoplatonist?},
    Volume = {32},
    Year = {1997}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=historische-zeitschrift, maxnames=2, hyperref=true, backref=true, backrefstyle=none, backend=bibtex,idemtracker=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
%
\makeatletter%
\renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \newunit}%
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}%
     {\renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit}}%
\makeatother%
%
\begin{document}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{athanasius1857}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 22]{stead1997}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't why you interfere with the `thebibliography` environment, which has nothing to do with `biblatex` itself. Moreover, you don't have to use a `\makeatletter-\makeatother` pair, since you do'nt use `@` in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution and I am posting it here if anyone else ever needs it (and maybe someone will correct me if I did something I shouldn't have done).

This makes it disappear from the main text:

```
\newbibmacro*{onlypages}{%
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \newunit}
%
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
%     \newunit\newblock
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
%     \newunit\newblock
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{note}%
%     \newunit\newblock
  \setunit*{\newunitpunct}%
\usebibmacro{onlypages}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

and this needs to be added after text but before bibliography to make it add pages in the bibliography:

```
\renewbibmacro*{onlypages}{%
      \printfield{chapter}%
      \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
      \printfield{pages}%
      \newunit}%
```

Answer (score 1):

Writes only the contents of entrytype `chapter` if it is an article

```
\renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
     \printfield{pages}%
     \newunit
    }}
```

Comment: Thank you but I am afraid this is not what I need (maybe I didn't explain it good?) I need a macro that will do the same thing for the article that the one above is doing for the incollection. I still want to keep the same thing for the incollection. So basically it needs to do this both for the article and incollection. Btw the one you posted is not doing it even for the article (at least not in that MWE I posted.